# How can I convert four bytes of hexadecimal into a floating point number within Excel

Tags: excel, hex

I have copied a stream of hexadecimal data from a Wireshark capture into Excel as a text value with no spaces.

`04000000ffffffff2b010000c900000000000000000000000000000000000000`

I know how to convert a section of this to an integer in Excel using the formula:

`=HEX2DEC(MID(B173,19,2) & MID(B173,17,2))`

which in this case returns 299.

But how do I do something similar to retrieve a float?  Some articles I've found discuss writing a C# program but I'm just trying to setup a little debug environment in Excel.  Other articles only seem to discuss doing the conversion in the other direction but I couldn't figure out the inverse procedure.

Edit:  An example of what I am after is:

`=SOMEFUNCTION("d162c240")`  --> 6.075

or possibly

`=SOMEFUNCTION("c240" & "d162")`  --> 6.075

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a mission!  But for anybody interested I got there, ending up with a custom LAMBDA function **HexToFloat()** that was built without the need for VBA.  The LAMBDA function and several other functions used are new in Excel 365 - if you're getting errors reproducing the functions below you might have an older version.

The Wikipedia page [Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_standard:_binary32) was my primary reference, in particular the section [Converting binary32 to decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Converting_binary32_to_decimal).

[image: IEEE 754 standard: binary32]

Read the article for a full understanding (good luck!!), but for TLDR it's worth noting that there is an implied bit that is not actually stored in memory and when combined with the fraction component this is referred to as the "significand".

For my solution I had to build several supporting LAMBDA functions in Excel's Name Manager.  In my case the data was stored as Little-Endian so if this is not applicable in your case you can skip that step.

| Name | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| LittleEndianHex | Interpret Hex data as Little Endian by reversing it in 2-byte chunks |

```
=LAMBDA(HexData,MID(HexData,7,2) & MID(HexData,5,2) & MID(HexData,3,2) & MID(HexData,1,2))
```

| Name | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| HEXtoBIN | Handles bigger numbers than the native Excel HEX2BIN function |

```
=LAMBDA(number,[places],LET(Unpadded,REDUCE("",HEX2BIN(MID(number,SEQUENCE(LEN(number)),1),4),LAMBDA(result,byte,result & byte)),REPT("0",IF(ISOMITTED(places),0,places-LEN(Unpadded))) & Unpadded))
```

| Name | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| BINtoDEC | Handles bigger numbers than the native Excel BIN2DEC function |

```
=LAMBDA(E,SUMPRODUCT(MID("0"&E,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN("0"&E))),1)*2^(LEN("0"&E)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN("0"&E))))))
```

| Name | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| HexToFloat | Convert hexadecimal representation of little-endian IEEE 754 binary32 (4 bytes) number to Single-precision floating-point format |

```
=LAMBDA(HexData,LET(LEHex,LittleEndianHex(HexData),Binary,HEXtoBIN(LEHex,32),bSign,LEFT(Binary,1),bExponent,MID(Binary,2,8),bImplicit,IF(bExponent=REPT("0",8),"0","1"),bSignificand,bImplicit & RIGHT(Binary,23),dSign,BIN2DEC(bSign),dExponent,BINtoDEC(bExponent),dSignificand,BINtoDEC(bSignificand),(-1)^dSign*(dSignificand*2^-23)*2^(dExponent-127)))
```

Once you've done all this you can enter the HexToFloat formula directly into a cell, e.g. `=HexToFloat(A1)` or `=HexToFloat("d162c240")`.  This particular example returns the result 6.07456254959106.

(PS  I've never asked for votes before but this took me *weeks*!  If you find it useful please consider giving me an up-tick.)

Comment: Extraordinary! Superb!

Comment: this is amazing!  I used this today and just had to omit the LittleEndianHex formula in the final function for my use.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer = DEC2HEX('Your reference cell or value')

Your formula shifts places of low and high byte of when you extract the  hex value from your string. Hex is just like all other position based numbers, where the lowest value is found on the right side.

[This person explain working with hex values in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/479948/how-to-format-a-microsoft-excel-2007-cell-in-hexadecimal)

[Debug of your formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHMlQ.jpg)

You can use multipe stages in one formula like:

```
=DEC2HEX(SUM(HEX2DEC("c240");HEX2DEC("d162")))
```

Note: If you use US settings in Office replace ; with ,

Comment: Thanks for your response but that's not what I asked.  I've added an example to my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your functions, Wayne. Perfectly done! But when I entered 3900 values to a worksheet it showed very bad performance.

So, I would like to propose an alternative solution which consists of the COM library.
[image]

The code:

```
Function Hex2Float(hexstr As String)
    Dim mbu As clModbUtils
    Set mbu = New clModbUtils
    Hex2Float = mbu.Hex2Float(hexstr)
End Function
```

Library's code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Globalization;
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IModbUtils {
    [Description("Conversion error")]
    bool Error{get; set;}
    [Description("Convert 4 bytes hexadecimal string to float")]
    float Hex2Float(string hexstr);
}
[Description("Utilities for MODBUS data processing")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class clModbUtils : IModbUtils{
    public bool Error{get; set;}
    public float Hex2Float(string hexstr){
        float result = 0; Error = false;
        try {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hexstr)) Error = true;
            else {
                var bts = BitConverter.GetBytes(Int32.Parse(hexstr, NumberStyles.HexNumber));
                byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
                bytes[0] = bts[2]; bytes[1] = bts[3];
                bytes[2] = bts[0]; bytes[3] = bts[1];
                result = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
            }
        }
        catch { Error = true; }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hex2Float accepts the 'Mid-Little Endian (CDAB)' hex string as identified by [Online Hex Converter](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/). It matches the order in the MODBUS transmission (low word first).

To compile and register the library use (the for 64b platform):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -target:library -platform:x64 ModbUtils.cs
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe -tlb -codebase ModbUtils.dll
```

It requires .NET Framework 4.8 (lower versions should be suitable as well). The platform should match the Excel platform. For 32b use '\Framework\' and 'platform:x86' above.

Of cause, it's possible to create full-fledged Excel Add-in, but the way I used requires less tools (no Visual Studio). The source code can be edited using any text editor - easy to modify, extend and advance.

Once again, simple steps to use this solution:

1. Check/install .NET Framework.
2. Modify the code of the library as required.
3. Compile and register the library.
4. Run Excel and add ModbUtils reference to your workbook.
5. Create function wrappers (as depicted) to use functions in sheet calculations.